# How to remove permission of "Shared with people" in the item of a list in workflow?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, permissions

I created a simple workflow in Sharepoint designer 2013, and there is only one step in it, which is to remove the permission of that item, I can see there is a "Remove List Item Permissions" in the action

[image]

But here's the problem:
I am unable to remove permission in the "Shared with" people list, for example, this item is shared with these people:

[image]

What I want to do is to remove the edit permission in this list, instead of adding the group one by one in sharepoint designer, is there a way to select all groups and users?

[image]

I am unable to use "Everyone" since that item is not shared to "Everyone".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **Replace** instead of remove. This will remove all users and explicitly add the ones that you select.

[image: Replace permissions]

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get your idea, but the problem is: the item originally isn't shared to "everyone", which means not all the users are allowed to "read", if I apply your settings, then all the users will be able to "read" that item. What I want to do is just remove the "edit" permission of the shared persons or groups